# App Engine - Pull queues max_concurrent_requests limit?

Tags: google-app-engine, pull-queue

I'm using Google App Engine pull queues to send massive push notifications to APNS, GCM and OneSignal mostly following this architecture: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/07/google-app-engine-takes-pain-out-of-sending-ios-push-notifications.html

[image]

The problem is that I'm hitting some kind of limit about how many tasks are leased at the same time: my Notification Workers lease 3 notifications at a time, but when there are more than about 30 workers running, `leaseTasks()` returns an empty array, even when there are hundreds or thousands of pending tasks. As far as I know, there is no limit about how many tasks are leased at the same time, so this behaviour is unexpected.

Comment: `max_concurrent_requests` cannot be set for pull queues. It's supposed that they have unlimited leases, but this proves that is not true.

Comment: Ah, misread your question...

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this limit of pull queues in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/overview-pull):

> If you generate more than 10 LeaseTasks requests per queue per second,
>   only the first 10 requests will return results. The others will return
>   no results.

If you have 30 workers, it seems that you could easily hit this limit.  Could you lease more tasks at a time and use fewer workers?

Comment: That must be it. I'll try to lease more tasks or backoff to get new leases. Thank you!